# JQuery/Javascript for Div resizing, expand and collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Any help will be appreciated.

I have 3 divs, the parent div(red), 2 child divs at the top(blue) and another on the bottom(green). Here is what I want to achieve:

When the top div(blue) resizes/increases its size by clicking the "Expand Blue Div" button, the bottom div(green) will shrink/decreases its size but remain in its position, meaning, it should still remain on its x-Axis even though it change its height. In short, regardless of the height of the bottom div(green), it should still remain on its position.

I want it also to revert back all of their original sizes when click on "Shrink Blue Div" button. Both Green and blue sizes will be on their original sizes.

I prefer a full jquery/javascript solution on this one. Thank you all

***PLEASE NOTE***
    The javascript code should NOT use  constant numbers for computation of size/height of "GREEN" div. For example, "greendiv.height = 100 - 5px"   <<, we should avoid using constants for this one.

```js
$("#expandDiv").click(function(){
 $("#blueDiv").css("height","150px");
});
```

```css
.parent_container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 400px;
}
.blue_box {
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.green_table {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  position:relative;
  height:250px;
}

.btn_actions {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="btn_actions">
    <button class="btn" id="expandDiv">Expand Blue Div</button>
    <button class="btn" id="shrinkDiv">Shrink Blue Div</button>
  </div>
  <div class="blue_box" id="blueDiv">
    
  </div>
  <div class="btn_actions">
    <button class="btn">Download Data</button>
    <button class="btn">Sort Data</button>
  </div>
  <div class="green_table">
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koykoys/0zLpgzsn/1/

[image: Here is my mock up image.]

Comment: what you need is an open/closed class that are different in height only. When you click on one div use javascript to add the open class and at the same time remove the closed class from the other div

Comment: Thank you for the response Martin, but I have  a table inside "Green" div, if I will create 2 classes, therfore, the data will be transferred for one class to another right?

Comment: The content inside the "Green" div shouldn't be transferred as thats all part of "Green" div's mark up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$("#expandDiv").click(function(){
   var $blueDiv = $("#blueDiv"), $greenDiv = $(".green_table");
   var blueDivHeight = $blueDiv.height(), greenDivHeight = $greenDiv.height();
   var updatedblueDivHeight = 150;
   var incrementedblueDivHeight = updatedblueDivHeight - blueDivHeight; 
     $blueDiv.height(updatedblueDivHeight);
   $greenDiv.height(greenDivHeight - incrementedblueDivHeight);
});
```

See demo at https://jsfiddle.net/0zLpgzsn/2/

Comment: Woah!! thank you very much @Dhananjay, this is exactly what I want to achieve , but can you please also help me to revert back all of their sizes when clicked on "Shrink blue div"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want CSS only solution, than take a look at this:

```css
.parent-container {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

label[for=toggle-blue]::before {
    content: 'Expand';
}

.blue-container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    flex-grow: 5;
}

#toggle-blue {
    display: none;
}

#toggle-blue:checked + label::before {
    content: 'Shrink';
}

#toggle-blue:checked + label + div {
    flex-grow: 20;
}

.green-container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    flex-grow: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
    <input id="toggle-blue" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="toggle-blue"></label>
    <div class="blue-container">

    </div>
    <div class="green-menu">
        <button>
            Button 1
        </button>
        <button>
            Button 2
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="green-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

It uses [CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), as well as [::before Pseudo Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

Comment: Thank you skobaljic, but I really prefer a jquery solution for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Code:

```
$("#expandDiv").click(function(event){
$('#shrinkDiv').removeClass('shrinked');
if(!$(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
    $("#blueDiv").animate({
        height: "+=150"
  });
  $(".green_table").animate({
    height: "-=150"
  });
  $(this).addClass('expanded');
} 

});

$("#shrinkDiv").click(function(event){

if( (!$(this).hasClass('shrinked')) && ($('#expandDiv').hasClass('expanded')) ) {
    $("#blueDiv").animate({
        height: "-=150"
  });
  $(".green_table").animate({
    height: "+=150"
  });
  $(this).addClass('shrinked');
}
      $('#expandDiv').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

Here is the working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0zLpgzsn/4/

Comment: Hi sir,thank you for this wonderful solution, it really works but its my mistake that I forgot to add on my description that we should not use constant/fixed numbers to change the size of "Green" div, but this answer is very useful ;), thank you very much

Comment: U can calculate the height dynamically and stored in a variable. Use it according to ur purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*CSS*/

  <style type="text/css">
  .parent_container {
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
  }
  .blue_box {
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid blue;
  }
  .green_table {
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 5px solid green;
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
  }
  .open{
    height:150px;
  }
  .closed{
    height:35px;
  }

  .btn_actions {
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>

// jQuery

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#expandDiv").on("click", function(){

    if(!$("#blueDiv").hasClass("open")){
      $("#blueDiv").addClass("open");  
    }
    if(!$(".green_table").hasClass("closed")){
        $(".green_table").addClass("closed");
    }

  })

  $("#shrinkDiv").on("click", function(){

    if($("#blueDiv").hasClass("open")){
      $("#blueDiv").removeClass("open");  
    }
    if($(".green_table").hasClass("closed")){
        $(".green_table").removeClass("closed");
    }


  })

})
```

This is based on your solution and requitrements :)

Plus link to fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/M4rt1985/5p1ddjtf/)

Comment: Hi sir,thank you for this wonderful solution, it really works but its my mistake that I forgot to add on my description that we should not use constant/fixed numbers to change the size of "Green" div, but this answer is very useful ;), thank you very much

Comment: @Reymark not problem, its a simple solution and can be tweaked :)